# MVC 3.0 View one string variable include the html is possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In above MVC 3.0 View one string variable include the html but not working

```
 string address = "-";
                if (Model.Landmark != null)
                {
                    address = Model.FlatBuildingName + " " + Model.RoadStreet + " " + Model.Landmark +"</br> "+ Model.Pincode + " " + Model.Villagecity ;
                }
```

include the html tag  but out show the

### Out Put

```
FlatBuildingName RoadStreet Landmark</br>PincodeVillagecity
```

Comment: It is definitely possible as you are already doing that.. but if you are asking if it makes sense, I don't think so. Seems like a waste to make all those properties only to concatenate into one property.

Comment: And if I completely misunderstood your question, edit your question to make sense.

Comment: Correct `</br>`  to `<br />` and then go with the suggestion provided by @webdeveloper

Answer (score 1):

Try [HtmlHelper.Raw Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to write your string to the html document. Like this:

```
@Html.Raw(address)
```

But you should check and sanitize html with your own, because if your string will contain scripts they will be executed in browser.